# How to debug high half x86-64 kernel in QtCreator 4.3.0

Tags: debugging, kernel, qt-creator, x86-64

I am having problems when trying to debug high half x86-64 kernel in Qt Creator 4.3 (based on Qt 5.8). The thing is that any pointer pointing to an address which has bit 63 set (like 0xFFFF800000000000) does not appear on the variable list and can't be used in Expression Evaluator. With previous versions of Qt Creator (based on Qt 5.7 and 5.4) debugging was possible (with some issues, but possible).

I am pretty sure that this is a bug/regression in Qt Creator debug scripts but I don't think I am going to register on their website just to report a bug. I am rather looking for some kind of workaround.

I am using it to debug custom kernel in QEMU under Ubuntu but the problem affects regular Qt based applications as well. Debugging with GDB (version 7.11.1) itself works fine, but it's a pain.

Example:

```
char *ptr = nullptr; // ptr is visible
ptr = (char *)0xFFFF800000000000; // ptr becomes invisible
ptr = (char *)0xABCD1234; // ptr becomes visible again
ptr = (char *)0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF; // even here ptr is visible
ptr = (char *)0x8000000000000000; // but now it is invisible again
```

Comment: A pointer cannot be visible or invisible. It just has a value. What kind of visibility are you referring to? Is it some special window?

Comment: I am talking about it's visibility in Qt Creator's debug window (the one with local variables in it).